# Doctrine querybuilder that uses the object's method

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I need to build a query that returns all the users that got 'ROLE_ADMIN' as role (I use FOSUserBundle for that).

Il already tried this but it doesn't work, it throws me "Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, boolean given".

```
public function getAdminQueryBuilder() {

      return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
              ->where('u.hasRole(:role)', true)
              ->setParameter('role', 'ROLE_ADMIN')
      ;
    }
```

Note that without the where condition, it works and I got all users in dabatase returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you should call the `where`:

```
public function getAdminQueryBuilder() {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
              ->where('u.hasRole = :role')
              ->setParameter('role', 'ROLE_ADMIN')
    ;
}
```

Let me know if there are issues.

---

EDIT # 2

Try this instead:

```
public function getAdminQueryBuilder() {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
              ->where('u.roles LIKE :roles')
              ->setParameter('roles', '%ROLE_ADMIN%')
    ;
}
```

I think it should work, but not certain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it throws "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 54 near 'hasRole = :r': Error: Class AppBundle\UserBundle\Entity\User has no field or association named hasRole". Looks like it doesn't consider hasRole as a function?

Comment: Have you already considered `@Security("has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')")` routing annotation [as described here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#securing-controllers-and-other-code)?

Comment: Yes, that message means there is no `hasRole` field defined in the `User` Entity.

Comment: The User entity in my AppBundle extends the User entyti of FOSUserBundle that contains this method : `public function hasRole($role)
    {
        return in_array(strtoupper($role), $this->getRoles(), true);
    }`

Comment: The problem is is that is a method, not a property. I added a second edit. Since `roles` is an array. Try it please.